# DB and DBCollection not wroking in java

Tags: java, mongodb

When I create the object of DB and DBCollection it gives error does something new comes instead of them or I should use something else?

```
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;

public class MongoDB {
    public static MongoClient mongoClient;
    public static DB database;
    public static DBCollection  test;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        mongoClient = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"));
        database = mongoClient.getDatabase("MongoDBTutorial");
    }
}
```

Here is the screen shoot

[image]

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots. What do you mean by "is not working", what is the error message?

Comment: the red lines are error when I move cursor above its saying 'Cannot resolve symbol 'DBCollection'

Comment: @AbdolKarim Your imports in the code are not correct for MongoDB Java Driver 4.2.3. Please look at the tutorial code carefully and use them (you are trying older APIs but using a newer driver): [MongoDB JavaDriver quick Start](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.2/driver/getting-started/quick-start/).

Comment: Actually I checked but I couldn't find solve that can you please write here how or post on answer

Comment: Did you read the linked documentation? [Access a Collection](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.2/driver/getting-started/quick-start/#access-a-collection)